# How Redirect 404page to homepage in https without changing url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want redirect don't exist page to homepage without changing URL.

I use the following code in `.htaccess` file.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

.htaccess works well for http (it doesn't change the URL), but with https changes the current url.

Comment: Be more specific, what changing to what

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include `index.php` in case of errors without changing URL you can use the following code in `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

This code is valid for http and https.

If you want to redirect the http requests to https you can add the following code in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect an error message:
Instead of prompting a 404 Not Found error page, the site will redirect to the homepage:

```
    Redirect 404 Error pages to the home page
    ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/
```

Redirect a non-existing page to index.php

```
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

You can manually insert the html code below to the 404.php page as well.

```
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv = "refresh" content = "2; url = https://www.URL.com/404.php" />
     </head>
```